# How to connect to postgres database in botpress?

Tags: postgresql, chatbot, botpress

I am having issue connecting `botpress` localhost server to `postgres` database.
I have set a `.env` file in the directory where bp.exe is present.
I have referred many sites but was not able to connect to postgres
below is .env file

```
DATABASE=postgres
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/botpress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem (I build from source code).

It works when I put `.env` in path `packages/bp/dist`.